Matrox G200eW3 fails on Debian 12.5
I do have a server with Matrox G200eW3 (on-board) on Debian Bookworm, but graphic display fails. There is a small _ in the top left corner, but that's all. Still the terminals (ctrl-alt 2/3/4/5) are working.
When I put in Nvidea PCI Graphic all is fine.
lshw
 *-display
                   description: VGA compatible controller
                   product: Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics Controller
                   vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                   logical name: /dev/fb0
                   version: 04
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 66MHz
                   capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
                   configuration: depth=32 driver=mgag200 latency=64 maxlatency=32 mingnt=16 resolution=1680,1050
                   resources: irq:16 memory:40000000-40ffffff memory:41808000-4180bfff memory:41000000-417fffff memory:c0000-dffff

dmesg | grep mgag
[    1.939538] mgag200 0000:04:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    1.946779] [drm] Initialized mgag200 1.0.0 20110418 for 0000:04:00.0 on minor 0
[    1.989215] fbcon: mgag200drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.408649] mgag200 0000:04:00.0: [drm] fb0: mgag200drmfb frame buffer device

lsmod | grep mgag
mgag200                69632  0
drm_shmem_helper       20480  1 mgag200
drm_kms_helper        208896  3 mgag200
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 mgag200
drm                   614400  4 drm_kms_helper,drm_shmem_helper,mgag200

On another server with same Matrox GPU the lsmod for mgag200 shows used 1 and I have a graphic desktop display.
Removing the mgag200 with rmmod also the terminals are gone, still I can connect with ssh.
modprobe mgag200 does not report any error, still the used count of lsmod stays zero and there is no graphic desktop.
Don't know what's failing me ...
Updates:
NOK System:
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-22-amd64 root=UUID=3f8dc943-cfbc-4b4a-b5a0-9d6c3f71cfc8 ro quiet
OK System:
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-18-amd64 root=UUID=bd0680de-37e8-4b86-ad25-aa8e96914841 ro quiet
modprobe.d content is exact the same.
What's different is dmesg, in that the order of services is different. For example in the NOK system x86/tme comes first. In the NOK system mgag200 is very late, compared to the OK system.
I tried bookworm-backports kernel 6.7 with no help. I installed newer firmware-misc-nonfree with Matrox driver, no help.
All system files can be viewed here:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/0dtebhbmkazlh46u0gd20/AAVv3nVmQG5x-Y-DXWC7o_o?rlkey=wfrppslsfj5bhau8c74jaqqd6&dl=0
thx for any hints!

Do both servers boot the same kernel version, with the same /proc/cmdline, and the same contents of /etc/modprobe.d?

That is something I am going to check, but cannot at the moment - in the meantime I upgraded to Trixie (by changing the apt sources), and after a bit messing around I got the mgag200 correctly loaded. Now I am trying to make a clean install of Trixie and see if the issue is fixed.

Updated post with additional information and Dropbox link.
